# Please Tell me difference in Http Servlet and genericServlet?

Tags: java, servlets

Please Tell me difference between Http Servlet and Generic Servlet?

Comment: SO is for techincal problem. Google will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that GenericServlet is a generic, protocol independant servlet.
HttpServlet is suitable only for HTTP-based servlets